# UISearchBar - How can I prevent dismissing the scopeBar when the cancel button is tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uisearchbar

I want my `UISearchBar`'s scopeButtons to remain visible at all times, but even though I've set `searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES'`, the buttons are still dismissed with an animation if I begin a search and then cancel it.

Is there any way I can prevent the scopeBar being animated out when the search is cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

Since the scope bar is only meant to be used while the `UISearchController` is active, I approached the problem differently.

I make the `UISearchController` active immediately.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // Immediately activating the searchController keeps scope bar permanently visible
    searchController.isActive = true
    // Tapping the cancel button triggers this method, which quickly toggles the scope bar
    // But the cancel button isn't needed anyway, so hiding it solves the problem
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

But now that the `UISearchController` is always active, by default the `UINavigationBar` is hidden, which is probably not what you want. To fix that, I prevent it from being hidden in `viewDidLoad`

`searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

This approach means that I don't need to use `showsScopeBar` at all, because it is always visible while the `UISearchController` is active.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is interested, the following delegate method does it.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    return YES;
}
```